# Python: Variable name is 'syntax error'

Tags: python, variables, python-2.7, syntax, error-handling

I have been working on a small combat simulating program with damage and health and defense and stuff (just for fun), but I came across this 'syntax error.' The syntax error is caused by enemystr = str(enemydamage). I tried deleting that but it simply said that the print statement below that is a syntax error.

```
def enemyattack():
    enemyrandompick = random.randint(1, 4)
    if enemyrandompick == 1:
        enemydamage = (random.randint(1, 3) * (enemyattack - (defense * 1.25))
        enemystr = str(enemydamage)
        print "The enemy's attack hits you and takes away " + enemystr , "health, leaving you with" + str(int(health))
```

Comment: You forgot a close parenthesis on the previous line. (Always check the previous line when you get a mysterious syntax error, especially if deleting the line doesn't help!)

Comment: Time for you to switch to an editor that highlights errors like this. There's no excuse for wasting SO on such trivial mistakes.

Comment: @Barmar: Ease up. If you don't want to waste your time on this, then don't.

Comment: It's not just our time that he's wasting, it's also his own.

Comment: There's also a semantic error: `enemyattack` is the name of the function *and*  used as a local variable which will lead to a `TypeError` (unless you initialize the local variable somewhere in your function).

Answer (score 2):

There is a mismatching paranthesis on this line:

```
enemydamage = (random.randint(1, 3) * (enemyattack - (defense * 1.25)))
#                                                                     ^ Missing closing paranthesis
```

Comment: It's arguably more Pythonic to point out there's an unnecessary leading `(` on the line :)

Answer (score -1):

And I think that you've not declared the variable, 'health' either.

```
`print "The enemy's attack hits you and takes away " + enemystr , "health, leaving you with" + str(int(health))
                                                                                                         ^
`
```

Comment: The OP didn't obviously show the whole code, variable `health` must've been defined somewhere else plus It would spark a `NameError` instead of a `SyntaxError` if `health` wasn't defined

Comment: OK...I just thought that there was only one function in the whole script, sorry.